# find the number of elements of order 3 in an abelian group of order 120

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let order of G=120.
>   Then the  number of sylow 3 grs are (1+3k)=p.where p divides 8.
>   So k=0 or 1.
>   Which one i take?

Comment: Hint: in an abelian group every subgroup is normal.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear in your (second) statement if you mean $G$ to be abelian. If $|G|=120$, then $3$ is the highest power of $3$ dividing the order of the group $G$. Hence, if $S \in Syl_3(G)$, then $S \cong C_3$. So a pair of different Sylow 3-subgroups intersect trivially. Since $n_3:=\#Syl_3(G)$ divides $40$ (not $8$ as you stated) and $\equiv 1$ mod $3$, $n_3 \in \{1,4,10,40\}$. The number of elements of order $3$ is $2n_3$. An abelian group $G$ has $n_3=1$. For $G=S_5$, $n_3=10$.

Comment: Sir,What is the relation connecting no. of elements of order p and no. of sylow p subgroups in a group ?

Comment: Each Sylow $3$-subgroup here has order $3$. This implies that each pair of distinct Sylow $3$-subgroups intersect trivially. Each of them contains two elements of order $3$. So this explains the total number of elements of order $3$ being $2n_3$. In general a Sylow subgroup is more than just a cyclic group of prime order and there is no nice formula for the total number of elements of a particular order. However, the number of elements of order $p$ is always $\equiv -1$ mod $p$.

Comment: @NickyHekster: Sir,Is it possible to say that there will be $$\varphi(p)$$ elements of order p in a sylow p subgroup?Is this Just a coincidence that it works here...?

Comment: That is a coincidence. For example, if the Sylow subgroup would be isomorphic to $C_9$, the number of elements of order $3$ is $2$ while $\varphi(9)=6$, being the number of elements of order $9$.

Answer (score 3):

$$120=2^3.3.5$$

It is given that group is Abelian. Every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, number of sylow_3_subgroup is unique. Hence number of elements of order $3$ is $$\varphi(3)=2$$.